# Equation in Beamer customized with beamerhighlight

Tags: beamer, highlighting

I would like to replicate for this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{beamerhighlight}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Equation}
{
\colorlet{mathnodecolor}{orange!60}
\tikzset{math color=orange}
\tikzset{append text node style={outer sep=2pt,text=structure,font=\bfseries\mathversion{bold}}}
\tikzset{append math node style={inner sep=1pt,outer sep=2pt,fill=none}}
\tikzset{append link style={>=latex,->,orange!80,line width=1.5pt}}
\uncover<+->{\begin{multline*}
H = \int_{-\infty}^L \frac{dx}{2\pi} \left[ 
\frac{v_F}{%
\commentmathwithtext<+->[position={(250:2cm)},
        append text node style={align=left,text width=13.2em},
            ]{K^2}{Luttinger parameter\\ ($K=1$ without interactions)}
} \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \right)^2 + v_F \left(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} \right)^2 \right]
- 
\commentmathwithtext<+->[position={(40:2cm)}]{V}{Backscattering}
\cos(2 \phi(x=0)) \\
+ \frac{1}{\pi^2} E_C \left[ \phi(x=0) - \left( \frac{\pi C 
\commentmathwithtext<+->[position={(-60:2cm)}]{V_g}{Gate voltage}
}{\lvert e \rvert} + k_F L \right) \right]^2
\end{multline*}}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

To produce such a pdf file: [image: Equation]

by substituting the equation above by this one:

```
\begin{gather}\label{sys:1}
\begin{dcases}
 \dot{Q} & = - \gamma_Q Q - \eta_1 k_0 Q - \eta_2 k_0 Q   - (1- \eta_1 - 
 \eta_2) \beta(Q) Q +  \\
& +    2(1- \eta_1 - \eta_2) \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma_Q \tau } \beta(Q_{\tau}) 
Q_{\tau}  + \eta_1 k_0 \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma_Q \tau } Q_{\tau} - 
\tilde{r}_q(P) Q^{q+1}, \\
\dot{D} & = - \kappa D + K,    \\
\dot{P} & = - v P + \kappa D,
\end{dcases}
\end{gather}
```

with the following data:

1. $Q$ est  la densité de  la  population de la cellule souche.
2. $\eta_1$ est la valeur en pourcentage de la division asymétrique avec la cellule fille indiscernable à la cellule mère.
3. $(1-\eta_1 - \eta_2)$  a la propriété de s'auto-renouveler.
4. $\tau$ est la durée du cycle cellulaire.

I would like to thank everyone who read this Post.

I sincerely thank for any comments or answers.

Comment: Where can one find the `beamerhighlight` package and where is `\commentmathwithtext` defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After downloading `beamerhighlight.sty` from [here](http://science.thilucmic.fr/index.php?c=la&p=highlighting) I could make your MWE run through and the new equation can be done with the same commands (if one also loads `mathtools`. Personally I would neither use equation numbers in presentations nor the large brace, but I guess you'll have the last word.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{beamerhighlight}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{New equation}
\colorlet{mathnodecolor}{orange!60}
\tikzset{math color=orange}
\tikzset{append text node style={outer sep=0pt,text=structure,font=\bfseries\mathversion{bold}}}
\tikzset{append math node style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=2pt,fill=none}}
\tikzset{append link style={>=latex,->,orange!80,line width=1.5pt}}
\begin{gather}\label{sys:1}
\begin{dcases}
 \dot{Q} & = - \gamma_Q Q
  - \eta_1 k_0  \commentmathwithtext<+->[position={(40:2cm)},
        append text node style={align=left,text width=13.2em},
            ]{Q}{la densit\'e de la population de la cellule souche}
 - \eta_2 k_0 Q   - (1- \eta_1 - 
 \eta_2) \beta(Q) Q +  \\
& +    2\commentmathwithtext<+->[position={(-100:4cm)},
        append text node style={align=left,text width=13.2em},
            ]{(1- \eta_1 - \eta_2)}{la propri\'et\'e de s'auto-renouveler}
     \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma_Q \commentmathwithtext<+->[position={(-70:3cm)},
        append text node style={align=left,text width=13.2em},
            ]{\scriptstyle \tau}{la densit\'e de la population de la cellule souche} } \beta(Q_{\tau}) 
Q_{\tau}  +  \commentmathwithtext<+->[position={(-40:2cm)},
        append text node style={align=left,text width=13.2em},
            ]{\eta_1}{la valeur en pourcentage de la division asym\'etrique avec
            la cellule fille indiscernable \'a la cellule m\'ere}
 k_0 \mathrm{e}^{-\gamma_Q \tau } Q_{\tau} - 
\tilde{r}_q(P) Q^{q+1}, \\
\dot{D} & = - \kappa D + K,    \\
\dot{P} & = - v P + \kappa D,
\end{dcases}
\end{gather}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better remove etex, it shouldn't be necessary in a a current tex system.